# How to move a DevOps account from a microsoft account to a Office 365 corporate account?

Tags: active-directory, office365, devops, account

I have a personal devops account (previous VisualStudio) that I sign into with a Microsoft Account.  Now that we have Azure Active Directory via Premium Office 365, I want to move the devops account under the corporate profile to allow only users with an Active Directory account (corporate email account) to sign in.  How do I transfer the personal devops account to my corporate profile?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

### Manual process

- invite an AAD user from. Your directory into the account and make them account owner.
- connect the organisation to AAD from the organisation settings panel.
- delete all MSA users
- invite all AAD users
- fix all security assignments & work item asignments

### Through support

- contact support about your intentions
- receive an excel file with all users
- map all MSA users to AAD users
- ask support to perform the transition

Comment: Finally resolved.  You have to change the Owner from a MSA account to an AAD account.  Adding the AAD account was easy.  However, changing the Owner of the organization to the AAD account was not obvious since it did not appear in the droplist.  It turns out you just need to type in the email account of the AAD account.  The change owner form could make this more clear.  Support staff were great on resolving the issue.